# Hashing bitarray ? Counting

Tags: python, dictionary, counting, bitarray

It seems for some reason that a dict can not have a non-duplicate key which is bitarray() 
ex.:

```
data = {}
for _ in xrange(10):
   ba = ...generate repeatable bitarrays ...
   data[ba] = 1

print ba
```

> {bitarray('11011'): 1, bitarray('11011'): 1, bitarray('11011'): 1, bitarray('01111'): 1, bitarray('11110'): 1, bitarray('11110'): 1, bitarray('01111'): 1, bitarray('01111'): 1, bitarray('11110'): 1, bitarray('11110'): 1}

You can clearly see that duplicate are stored as different keys (f.e. first two elements) !! which is weird. What could be the reason.
My goal is simply to count the number of times a bit pattern shows up, and of course Dict's are perfect for this, but it seems that bitarray() for some reason is opaque to the hashing algorithm.
btw.. i have to use bitarray(), cause i do 10000 bits+ patterns.

Any other idea of efficient way of counting occurrence of bit pattens ..

Comment: You can't meaningfully use a bitarray as a dict key. Even trying should raise a TypeError, but the class has a bug where it inherits the default identity-based hash instead of using PyHash_NotImplemented.

Answer (score 1):

This answer addresses your first confusion regarding duplicate dictionary keys and I assume you're referring to `bitarray()` from [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) module, *I've not used this module myself.

In your example above, you're not actually getting duplicate dictionary keys, you might see them that way, but they're duplicates to the naked eye only, for instance:

```
>>> class X:
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return '"X obj"'
...  
>>> x1 = X()
>>> x2 = X()
>>> d  = {x1:1, x2:2}
>>> d
{"X obj": 2, "X obj": 1}
```

But `x1` isn't exactly equals to to `x2` and hence they're not duplicates, they're distinct objects of class `X`:

```
>>> x1 == x2
False 
>>> #same as
... id(x1) == id(x2)
False
>>> #same as 
...x1 is x2
False
```

Moreover, because `X` class defines `__repr__` which returns the string representation for its objects, you would think dictionary `d` has duplicate keys, again there are no duplicated keys nor are the keys of type `str`; key of value 1 is `X` object and key of value 2 is another object of `X` -- literally two different objects with a single string representation returned by their class's `__repr__` method:

```
>>> # keys are instance of X not strings
... d
{"X obj": 2, "X obj": 1}    
>>> d["X obj"]
KeyError: 'X obj'
>>>[x1]
1
>>>[x2]
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Till `BitArray 0.8.1` (or later) I believe it does not satisfy the hash invariant property.

To work around it, you should convert the bit array to `byte` format as follows.

```
>>> from bitarray import bitarray
>>> l = [bitarray('11111'), bitarray('11111'), bitarray('11010'), bitarray('11110'), bitarray('11111'), bitarray('11010')]
>>> for x in l: ht[x.tobytes()] = 0
... 
>>> for x in l: ht[x.tobytes()] += 1
... 
>>> ht
{'\xf8': 3, '\xf0': 1, '\xd0': 2}
```

Remember you can get back the `bitarray` from the `byte` format by using the command `frombytes(byte)`. Though, in this case you will have to keep track of the size of `bitarray` explicitly as it will return `bitarray` of size multiple of 8.

If you want to keep the `bitarray` in the dictionary also:

```
>>> from bitarray import bitarray
>>> l = [bitarray('11111'), bitarray('11111'), bitarray('11010'), bitarray('11110'), bitarray('11111'), bitarray('11010')]
>>> ht = {}
>>> for x in l: ht[x.tobytes()] = (0, x)
... 
>>> for x in l: 
...     old_count = ht[x.tobytes()][0]
...     ht[x.tobytes()] = (old_count+1, x)
... 
>>> ht
{'\xf8': (3, bitarray('11111')), '\xf0': (1, bitarray('11110')), '\xd0': (2, bitarray('11010'))}
>>> for x,y in ht.iteritems(): print(y)
... 
(3, bitarray('11111'))
(1, bitarray('11110'))
(2, bitarray('11010'))
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it :

```
desc = bitarray(res).to01()
if desc in data : data[desc] += 1
else : data[desc] = 1
```

gosh I miss perl no-nonsense autovivification :)

Comment: `.tobytes()` would produce a much more compact object that is suitable for use as a dictionary key.  And a `collections.Counter` would be much easier to use in this situation than a raw dictionary.